# Review completed but no edits or deletion

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review-queues, not-an-answer

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/18174785

4 reviews recommending deletion. No deletion or edits. Yet it's review completed.

What happened here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the time the review was completed, it had a positive score (+1), which prevents automatic deletion from going through and instead raises a flag for moderators to double-check and make sure the answer really should be deleted.

Comment: Ironically, [the timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47679876/timeline) shows that not only did that answer go through the [LQP queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/18174785), but also *both* a [first posts review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/18174575) and a [late answer review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/18174728).

Comment: We need to make triple-sure that it should be deleted.  I think the missing detail in this answer is that there is a time-out, posts don't stay in the queue forever and 4 is not enough.  And Cody hasn't been seen for a month, hope he's okay.

Comment: @HansPassant Four actually is enough. It was decreased from 6 on Stack Overflow on June 30.

Comment: So everybody voted "delete this crap" and then it doesn't get deleted until you show up.  Got it.  SO still throws me for a loop after 9 years of using it.